# Doctrine query builder

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I am using a doctrine 2 in symfony3.4 and I have a complex query which is :

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder(
                        'SELECT id FROM AppBundle:Room  WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT room_id FROM AppBundle:Bookings  WHERE  NOT ( checkOut <= :check_in OR checkIn >= :check_out ) ) ORDER BY id'
                )
                ->setParameter('check_in', $request->query->get('check-in'))
                ->setParameter('check_out', $request->query->get('check-out'))
                ->getQuery();

        return $rooms = $query->execute() ;
```

my problem is when I execute this query , I get an error which is :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 7: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got 'SELECT'
```

Comment: thank you for your useful answer . I know the question is written badly, but I think you got what I meant

Comment: I think it is clear now

Answer (score 1):

The createQueryBuilder method expects a string as first parameter but you are providing a full query statement and the result would be something like this:

> select **select id...** from table

an that raises an exception the bold part is your query inside the createQueryBuilder method.

Try this instead:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('alias')->addSelect('alias.id')
->where(...)
->orderBy(...)
```

Hope it helps

> EDIT

inside the where you put what is after the where in your old code but with the query builder you can build your query without the sql and let doctrine build the query for you

check this [doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Comment: could you please write the rest of the code , what I have to put inside the where ?

Comment: @Mostafa don't ask for the rest of the code, he provides you with a solution and docs so go ahead and read it, try by yourself and do not expect someone here build the code for you! Good luck